# Scaling by percentage - is this appropriate given this situation?

Tags: regression, inference, percentage, feature-scaling

Let's say I have a range of formulations, and each formulation contains a different starting rate of water "x", and I want to test how fast the formula dries out over time (ie. loss of water over time), and put this on a plot. Let's suppose the starting rate of x for each formulation is known, but there is no control for over the starting rate of x. In order to make the regression on the plot between each formulation more comparable, is it appropriate to scale x for each formula to be the same starting rate?

For instance: x1: 20, x2: 35, x3: 22

And then, to scale each resulting regression I could just adjust each data point by ~57% for x2, and ~91% for x3; so that they all have a starting rate of x = 20 and scale the remainder of the data points by those same percentages for x2 and x3?

Thank you!

This is also similar to a question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238615/percentage-scaling) (also on stackexchange!) incase my post doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a survival analysis problem. Survival analysis involves analysing time-to-event data (traditionally, time until death in medical analyses, hence the name, but the event can be anything).

In this case, your event is the drying of the formulation, and you have a covariate which is the amount of water in the formulation. A good place to start could be fitting a survival regression model with amount of water `x` as a predictor.

Survival analysis is quite a flexible technique and allows for various distributions describing the time to event data, multiple predictors etc.